# PHP set int length

Tags: php, int

Alright simple question

I have integriters like

```
5
188
4634
```

And they all need to be formated to

```
0000000005
0000000188
0000004634
```

It can become a string that doesnt matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is the function for that:

```
$num = sprintf("%010d", $num);
```

Answer (score 3):

[str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad)

```
echo str_pad($str, 10, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
#how many chars will be in the string
$filltotal = 10;
$number = 5;
#with str_pad function the zeros will be added
 echo str_pad($number, $fill, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

// The result: 0000000005

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is str_pad:

```
echo str_pad($num, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve by this.

```
$val = 12;
for($i=0;$i<(10 - count($val));$i++)
{
    $str .= '0';
}
$final_val = $str.$val;
```